# Regex: How can I get the last word in an HTML string ignoring HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code in Javascript:

```
html.replace(/(\S+)\s*$/, '<span class="highlight-word">$1</span>');
```

I'd like to highlight the last word in the HTML string; however, if there is an HTML tag at the end, that tag will be wrapped with the "highlight-word" span.

For example:

```
This is a test <br> <b> hello there </b>
```

Will become:

```
This is a test <br> <b> hello there <span class="highlight-word"></b></span>
```

How can I correct the above Regex, so that the outcome will be like so:

```
This is a test <br> <b> hello <span class="highlight-word">there</span> </b>
```

Comment: Maybe a slightly different approach: Use `textContent` to retrieve the actual text, identify the last word there, and then use a regex to replace the last occurrence of that word.

Comment: I thought of that, but I will need to have the HTML tags still there.

Comment: The `textContent` part is just for identifying the last word, the replacement still happens in your original string.

Comment: If I have: <div id="divA">This is <span>some</span> text!</div> and use textContent for divA, the spans will be gone.  I need that HTML to still be in place where it was.

Answer (score 2):

The simple and elegant solution would be to replace your RegEx with the following pattern with look ahead.

```
(\w*)(?=\W*\<\/.*\>$)
```

This pattern only matches the last word before the close of any tag.

Comment: This is good; however, I am seeing that it's also matching empty chars at the end. See here: https://regex101.com/r/qWJzGA/2

Comment: ok, I got it! it's `(\w+)(?=\W*\<\/.*\>$)` Thanks! https://regex101.com/r/qWJzGA/3 Just need to change `(\w*)` to `(\w+)`.

Comment: Now there is another issue I have discovered. If there is a word after the HTML tag at the end, it will not highlight the word: https://regex101.com/r/qWJzGA/4

Comment: Hi, you specifically mentioned end of line. If it is not the end of line you will need to identify which is the main tag  you want to consider as closing tag. If you are looking at any and all HTML files then it will need to be updated as explained here.

Comment: I specified ignoring HTML tags, meaning all tags including <br>. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do everything in one step, you could take the following approach:

1. Get the `textContent` of your string, which omits all HTML tags.
2. From that extract the last word.
3. In the original string replace the last word with a wrapped version.

Assuming you work in a browser, this could look like that:

```js
function highlightLast( str ) {

  // create a wrapper to get the textcontent
  const wrapper = document.createElement( 'div' );
  wrapper.innerHTML = str;
  
  // get the last word
  const lastWord = wrapper.textContent.split( /\b/ ).pop();

  // highlight the last occurrence of that word
  return str.replace( new RegExp( `${lastWord}(?![\\s\\S]*${lastWord})` ), `<span class="highlight-word">${lastWord}</span>` );

}

console.log( highlightLast( '<div id="divA">This is <span>some</span> text</div>' ) );
console.log( highlightLast( '<div id="divA">This is text with <span>some</span> more text</div>' ) );
```

Note that there are some edge cases you might need to solve. In particular, if the word contains special characters, you need to escape them before creating the RegExp.

Comment: ok, so I tried this out.  The problem I'm having now is that when there is punctuation or white-space at the end, that gets wrapped with the "highlight-word" span.

Comment: Then filter the text content you got before retrieving the last word. Just remove anything you do not consider a word. For example, anything that does not have at least one letter or similar things.